# 18.04: After failed start of ubuntu live system (from DVD) BIOS can no longer be opened with F11

Tags: boot, uefi, 18.04, bios, livedvd

I've tried to start an Ubuntu Live System from DVD. (There should be no changes to my already installed system.)
I proceeded as follows:

1. Restart of Computer
2. During boot process pressed F11, as required according to screen message
3. Entering BIOS. There was a list to choose from. It started with an entry for my SSD with Windows 10. Second was an entry that started with "UEFI" and was followed by the DVD-drive. Then there were other entries for HDDs and another entry for the DVD-drive WITHOUT "UEFI" at the beginning.
4. I chose the second entry of the list (for the DVD-drive, starting with "UEFI")
5. Ubuntu started to boot but produced error messages and came to a halt. Error messages started with

> ```
> Could't get size: 0x000000000000000000000e
> MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
> ....
> ```

6. Restarted computer
7. Pressing F11 during booting shows no effect. Since then I have tried serveral times but F11 does not work anymore.
   Windows 10 is still working.

Can anybody tell me what went wrong? 
I would like to restore the old state so that BIOS is working as usual, i.e. F11 can be used to enter BIOS.

My system:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700
- mobo: MSI B350 Gaming pro carbon
- RAM: 2 x 16GB 2666-16 Vengeance LPX
- SSD: 512 GB Samsung 860 ProBasic (+ Windows 10)
- HDD: WD 3TB Blue
- GPU: Gainward GTX 1080 Phoenix

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful for you any more but I had the same issue on the same motherboard and I fixed it by clearing the bios.

I did this by unplugging the PSU and removing the onboard battery.  Left it for about 15 minutes and it booted up. Had nothing to do with the OS and the built in "Restore Defaults" in the bios did nothing for the issue.

Prior to the step above I tried unplugging all hardware except CPU/RAM and booting to USB. I still received the UEFI errors. The odd thing is that I think those are just cosmetic. After I fixed this and booted I still saw the UEFI errors but my PC booted past them.  I also think something else was the issue becaus when the PC would lock, my USB keyboard would lose backlight and nothing but a hard power off would do anything.